# how to change username and password in kali linux

Tags: linux, kali-linux

I want to change my password and username in kali Linux but I have found out that before changing password I should make sure of two things: 1- I'm using an active grub bootloader 2- my bootloader in not locked. I have no idea how I'm supposed to check this things out. I would appreciate any help either about this or how to change username and password.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What you have found out is irrelevant to changing your username. It seems you dont have the knowledge you need to use Kali - you may want to learn a more user friendly distro like Ubuntu first.

Comment: [Why is Kali Linux so hard to set up? Why won't people help me?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5361/53467)

Answer (score 0):

Linux: Reset User Password

> I want to change my password and username in kali Linux

Changing password in Kali is not part of the Settings Manager (posted here from my Kali machine)

**To Change Password:**

Open a terminal window and run:

**sudo passwd USERNAME**

(where USERNAME is the name of the user whose password you want to change).

Type your user password.

Type the new password for the other user.

Retype the new password.

Close the terminal.

Restart your system to test.

**To Change Username:**

Best and safest way in any operating system is to make a new user with new user profile and password. Copy your data into the new profile and when fully tested, delete the user and profile you do not want.